# Duda respecto a código en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Espero se encuentren bien, estoy empezando con JS y tengo una duda:

```
function a() {
  return {
    imprimir: function() {
      return console.log("Hola")
    }
  }
};
```

La función a retorna un objeto que tiene una sola propiedad llamada `imprimir`, la cuál alberga una función que retorna un `console.log()` el cuál imprime un `Hola`.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma para acceder a la función que retorna ese `console.log()`?, ya que por ejemplo he intentado llamar a la función `a()` directamente pero claro, no aparece nada en consola ya que retorna otra función, y también intenté acceder a la función de la forma `a.imprimir();` pero por supuesto que aparece que no es una función.

Comment: La función `a` no retorna "otra" función,  retorna un objeto que tiene una propiedad llamada `imprimir`. Luego, `imprimir` es a su vez una función que retorna el resultado de la ejecución de `console.log`. Las funciones de `console` (`log`, `error`, `table`, etc.) devuelven `undefined`. Por lo tanto la función `imprimir` mostrará el mensaje "Hola" en consola y retornará `undefined`. La forma de acceder a `imprimir` sería algo como: `const obj = a();`, luego: `obj.imprimir();`. El resultado será la salida en consola de "Hola"

Comment: Una  "propiedad" que contiene una función, se llama "método".

Comment: Correcto @ArnauCastellví, se llama "método".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para tener acceso al objeto que se construye dentro de la función `a()` y que es retornado por ella, primero debes invocar a la función misma.

Puedes almacenar el objeto que retorna y luego, sobre ese objeto, invocar la función `imprimir()`, por ejemplo:

```js
function a(){
    return{
        imprimir: function(){
            return console.log("Hola")
        }
    }
}

let obj = a();
obj.imprimir();
```

También puedes invocar directamente a la función *al vuelo*, es decir, sin almacenar el objeto retornado en una variable, sino directamente sobre el resultado de la función:

```js
function a(){
    return{
        imprimir: function(){
            return console.log("Hola")
        }
    }
}

a().imprimir();
```

Para afianzar el tema, podrás notar que el objeto construido por `a()` no es diferente de otros objetos. El hecho de que este tenga un miembro que es una función no es lo más relevante ni especial del objeto. Si no la tuviera, lo que he afirmado antes, aplica. Digamos que este objeto solo tuviera miembros comunes, digamos un nombre. Para acceder al valor del nombre, primero debes invocar a la función.

Puedes (o no) almacenar el objeto en una variable para tener acceso a sus miembros, por ejemplo:

```js
function a(){
    return {
        "nombre": "objeto a"
    }
}

console.log(a().nombre);
let obj = a();
console.log(obj.nombre);
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Que bueno ¿Se puede crear un array lista de esta forma?

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz, no estoy seguro de qué es lo que tienes en mente, pero de las cosas que se me ocurren a mi, no veo por qué no se podría.

Answer (score 2):

Si, con `a().imprimir();` ejecutas la función

Demo:

```js
function a(){
    return{
        imprimir: function(){
            return console.log("Hola")
        }
    }
}

a().imprimir();
```

---

Y si retornaras una función directamente sería

```js
function a(){
  return function(){
     return console.log("Hola")
  }
}

a()();
```

Y si retornaras una funcion que retorna otra función

```js
function a(){
  return function(){
    return function(){
        return console.log("Hola")
    }
 }   
}
a()()();
```

Comment: graciaaaaaaaaaas!!!!